# Installing and running Laravel and PHP without admin privileges on Linux servers

Tags: php, linux, laravel

There is a need for developing a web application that will be deployed on a Linux server on which I won't have admin privileges and also the internet.

I need to deploy self-contend binaries or other files on the server. I need a way to develop and deploy a web application in such a restricted environment.

My preferred development stack is Laravel but I am open for any other framework which can be used to develop the application for such a scenario.

Comment: This might be a better question for "ask fedora" since it's linux based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only answer on Laravel's behalf: Laravel alone requires only PHP binaries. It doesn't need internet, not even composer while in production mode. You can zip the entire application with fetched dependencies from another computer and deploy it anywhere you want.

As for other software, I'm sure you can download them as tarballs and install them as basic user without root privileges. Check out the PHP site for stable Linux releases: https://www.php.net/downloads.php